# Login screen using user custom control

Tags: c#, .net, forms, parent

I have followed some advices I got here today and would need a bit more help now:

I have an user control with login logic.
In mainForm I am using this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        LoginScreen login = new MainMenu();
                    login.Parent = this;
                    login.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    login.Show();
}
```

But I guess it is not modal and thus does not stop the original Form application. Sure I would need the main Form to do not continue until the login form is closed (and login sucessfull).

Would using an event correct? Let login object to raise an event that login was successfull and let the MainForm handle it - run the app?

EDIT: This is user control, no ShowDialog method available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`.

Besides, `ShowDialog()` returns a DialogResult, so you can check if user doesn't press `OK` and close the form in that case:

```
if(form.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.Close();
}else
{
    //if login it's ok continue with main form loading...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Given that it's a usercontrol:

- Create a new form class and add the user control in it (e.g. using designer)
- Instanciate it and call `ShowDialog()` in your `FormLoad` code (the code is similar to the one you posted, but you need to instanciate the login form instead of your usercontrol)

Comment: That user control does not have ShowDialog method :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `login.Show();` you might use`login.ShowDialog(this);`, making it a modal pop-up for the form.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not derived from the `Form` class (which is odd), just create a windows form and put your control on it, then call `ShowDialog` method of the form. You'll have to wire closing of the form to the controls on your login screen somehow, though. If it fires some events it shouldn't be a problem.